# Spring : Redirect Attribute Not Added To Model

Tags: java, spring

I have scenario where I'm redirecting to view, through two handles, In first handle I've used `@RedirectAttribute` and used its method `addFlashAttribute`.
This works fine if my attribute value (String) is without spaces or special characters, but with space and special characters it is not working.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addCategory")
public String addCategory(@ModelAttribute("category") Category category ,
                    @RequestParam int access,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes , Model model){
    System.out.println();
    if(categoryService.isCategoryExist(category).equals("category_not_exist")){
        categoryService.addCategory(category);
        //redirectAttributes.addAttribute("addedCategoryName", category.getCategoryName());
        System.out.println("isCategoryAdded YES " +category.getCategoryName().trim());
        System.out.println("Category Name  "+category.getCategoryName().trim());
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("isCategoryAdded", "yes");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("addedCategoryName", category.getCategoryName().trim());
    }
    else{
        //redirectAttributes.addAttribute("existCategoryName", category.getCategoryName());
        System.out.println("isCategoryAdded NO ");
        System.out.println("Category Name  "+category.getCategoryName().trim());
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("isCategoryAdded", "no");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("addedCategoryName", category.getCategoryName().trim());
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("addedCategoryName  *********  "+category.getCategoryName().trim());
    System.out.println();
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("paramCategoryId", category.getCategoryId());
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("paramCategoryName", category.getCategoryName());
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("paramParentCategoryId", category.getParentCategoryId());
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("paramMovement", "backward");
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("parentCategoryId", category.getCategoryId());  
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("access", access);  

    /*redirectAttributes.addAttribute("parentCategoryId", category.getParentCategoryId());*/
    return "redirect:/Category/categories";
}
```

In View JSP

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${ isCategoryAdded eq 'yes'}">
        <div class="successMessage">Category '${addedCategoryName }' added successfully.</div>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${ isCategoryAdded eq 'no'}">
        <div class="errorMessage">Category '${addedCategoryName }' already exist.</div>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Problem occurs only if Category name contails spaces and Special Characters

How to solve it ?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have an attribute named `addedCategoryName `, which is what you use in your JSP. Also what isn't working according to you?

Comment: If I type category name as e.g. 'Automotive'  which is without space it gives me message that Category  already present , but if I type category name as 'Automotive some / thing' it not showing any message

Comment: Make sure your encodings are correct and that your checks/validations are actually working. Next to that I wouldn't put that logic in the view as it doesn't belong there imho, it should be part of the controller.

Comment: I have set URIEncoding="UTF-8" in tomcat's server.xml , also added filter in web.xml CharacterEncodingFilter n set its init param encoding to UTF-8 but no effect

Comment: @M.Deinum also my redirectAttribute is not added to Model of redirected handle...